# Jquery Popup not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm  developing my website and I have a problem with the display of my popups. When picture is clicked, a function is called in order to put the picture in a popup. The probleme is when I click for the first time on the picture, it is not centered in the window and for the second time it's centered. It's weird, maybe the computation of the margin-top and margin-left is not well in my function.

JS :

```
function popup(rel, size){
    var popID = rel; //Find popup
    var popWidth = size; //find width

    //make display the popup
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': popWidth});

    //Releasing of margin, that allow to center the window 
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height()+20) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width()+20) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
      'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
      'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

   // appearance of the background - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) to correct bugs of oldest version of IE
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

    return false;
}
```

HTML :

```
    <div id="photoPopup" class="popup_block">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
    h1#titlePopup {
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 9px black;
}

div#photoPopup {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#fade { /*--Black opaque mask background--*/
  display: none; /*--default mask--*/
  background: #000;
  position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block{
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*--position fixed for IE6--*/
*html #fade {
position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
position: absolute;
}
```

If you want see the problem into the page "photo" : http://manuelmenneveux.pusku.com

Thank you anyway for your help :)

Comment: I understand you are using bootstrap why cant you use modelbox instead of your customized popup

Comment: Could you not use position relative and then margin auto? You will then just need to either calculate the margin top or give it a percentage so it is roughly alway eg 10% from the top

Comment: Thank you ;) But i think it's better to create it's own function than use directly library . Everyone can do it, use tutorial and make copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

For people who have the same problem than me I found the solution, it's because the popup is loaded before the picture is loaded, so the position is made depending to the size of popup. As the popup is empty before the loading of picture, the position is computed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice this. Apparently you've already solved this. Check out my answer anyway. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the image hasn't loaded and the centering relies on the image dimensions for that.

One possible solution is to get the image source from the image tag and load it into a dummy image node. Then you would check the dimensions on that dummy image node. You could either use those dimensions directly and size and center the div or calculate the aspect ratio and set the height or width to 100% and then center the div. Then you'd finally load the image inside.

Here's some code that might get you started.

Example HTML

```
<!-- Store image with data-src to prevent image from loading (if you want) -->
<img data-src='img.png'>
```

Example jQuery

```
// Image source
var imageSource = $('img').attr(imageSourceAttribute);

// Create image element
$('<img>').attr('src', imageSource).load(function() {

  // Native image dimensions
  // Note: $(this) won't work on in-memory images
  var nativeWidth = this.width,
      nativeHeight = this.height;

  // ... Do more things ...

  // Load image
  $('image').attr('src', imageSource);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will follow your advice Because for me I put a setTimeout but if users have a low internet speed the problem stay the same, the pictures will take long time to be loaded.

Comment: Yup, settimeouts aren't very reliable, imo. This is a more concrete solution.